# With Sitecore and FakeDB, how can you set a LookupField TargetItem?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sitecore, nunit

With FakeDB, how can I set the value of the TargetItem in a DbLinkField?

**The setup:**
I have a data template with a droplist that points to a list of other items.

I have a Sitecore Item extension method:

```cs
public static Item Lookup(this Item item, string fieldName)
{
    if (item == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
    LookupField field = item.Fields[fieldName];
    if (field == null) return null;
    return field.TargetItem;
}
```

**Unit Test and Result:**
When I run the following simple test against my code the LookupItem is found as a field, but the resulting LookupItem has a null TargetItem. Is it possible to mock this somehow using FakeDB?

```cs
[Test]
public void TestLookupItemExtension()
{
    ID templateId = ID.NewID;
    ID refItemId = ID.NewID;

    using (var db = new Db()
    {
        new DbTemplate("ItemTpl", templateId) { "Foo" },
        new DbItem("RefItem", refItemId),
        new DbItem("ItemComponent", ID.NewID, templateId)
        {
            new DbLinkField("Foo") { TargetID = refItemId  }
        }
    })
    {
        var item = db.GetItem("/sitecore/content/itemcomponent");
        var lookupItem = item.Lookup("Foo");
        lookupItem.Should().NotBeNull();
    }
}
```

The result of the field in the targetitem looks like this:

```
field   {Sitecore.Data.Fields.LookupField}  Sitecore.Data.Fields.LookupField
+       InnerField  "Foo"-{{C906FD3D-C5DA-4191-8F0A-F15603FB897E}}  Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field
+       TargetID    {{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}}    Sitecore.Data.ID
+       TargetItem  null    Sitecore.Data.Items.Item
        Value   "<link />"  string
+       _innerField "Foo"-{{C906FD3D-C5DA-4191-8F0A-F15603FB897E}}  Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field
```

So I'm getting the LookupField correct, but it's never actually putting the TargetId or TargetItem into the resulting LookupField mock object.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are mixing LinkField and LookupField.
In your test you should define "Foo" as a LookupField. Something like this:

```
var field = new DbField("Foo") { Type = "Lookup" };
field.Value = refItemId.ToString();
var dbItem = new DbItem("ItemComponent", ID.NewID, templateId)
                     {
                        field
                     };
db.Add(dbItem);
```

Not sure if the type is even needed, but this worked for me.

Comment: Fantastic - that works as expected.  Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If (item == null) throw new argument.

Have you tried?

if (!empty($item)) {}

Maybe change your long ifs to simpler variables to play with before getting into the lookup field.

Can you do asynchronous file calling using js here? And have it come from json data?

Comment: Thanks Robert.  I think the issue is more surrounding how to set a TargetItem with FakeDB.  The item is valid when it comes in, and I can find the LookupField.  It's the `LookupField.TargetItem` that's coming up null :(